# Поиск по строке в php

Tags: php, строки, search

Нужно осуществить поиск по строке формата:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
```

Человек вводит в поиск **"sit ipsum amet"**. Можно ли проверить строку на наличие этих символов в строке, не в прямом порядке ?

В php есть стандартные методы для поиска по строке, например `stristr()`, но он сработает, только если в точном порядке дать ему данные, а мне нужно просто что-то, что найдёт совпадение в строке и запросе.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Разбивайте строку поиска на слова и ищите каждое слово отдельно.

Comment: используйте бд или поисковый движок на подобие sphinx

Comment: Обычно это востребовано в БД/поиск-движках. Но если уж надо на PHP - разбивать строку на слова, обрезать окончания, затем каждое слово искать в тексте регуляркой вроде `preg_match('@(^|\s)'.preg_quote($word).'@i', ;$text)`. Так можно заодно релевантность узнать, если объектов для сопоставления - много.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот этот код. В основ используеться [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/array_intersect)

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
$haystack = "sit ipsum amet";
$stringInArray = explode(' ', $string);
$haystackInArray = explode(' ', $haystack);

if(count(array_intersect($haystackInArray, $stringInArray)) == count($haystackInArray)) {
// Слова из строки найдены
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Основная идея - разбиваем обе строки (целевую и искомую)на слова. А затем циклом пробегаем по массиву искомых слов и ищем каждое слово в массиве целевых слов

```
function mixed_search($haystack, $needle) {
  $haystack_words = explode(' ', $haystack);
  $needle_words = explode(' ', $needle);
  foreach ($needle_words as $word) {
    if (array_search($word, $haystack_words) === false)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
$search = "sit ipsum amet";
echo mixed_search($string, $search);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.